# mailgun messages to authorized recipients end up in gmail spam

Tags: email, heroku, mailgun

I am trying to use mailgun to handle email submissions from a site on heroku. I have added my gmail (google enterprise) address as an authorized recipient, and I receive the emails, but they always go to spam, with the message

> Be careful with this message. The sender hasn't authenticated this message so Mail can't verify that it actually came from them. Avoid clicking links, downloading attachments, or replying with personal information.

I found the Mailgun resource on [Google Authentication](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036626153-Google-Authentication) but I'm not even sure if this is the right resource for fixing the problem, and I see no "Google Auth" option.

Does anyone know how to keep these messages from being flagged and sent to spam?

[image]

[image]